# Only one item being returned from array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am trying to echo out two items from an array like so..

```
    <?php
        $blogs = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'relatedblogposts', true );
            if (is_array($blogs) & $blogs != '' ) { 
                foreach($blogs as $blog) {
                echo $blog[url];
                echo $blog[link-title];
            }
        }
    ?>
```

When I run this the only thing that is returned is the $blog[url] section.  For some reason it is not returning [link-title].  If I run print_r($blogs); then I get..

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [url] => http://www.example.com [link-title] => Example Link Title ) )
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: In your print_r it does return the link-title.

Comment: Unrelated, your `if` statement has a single `&` (bitwise operator) instead of `&&`

Comment: [Why is `$foo[bar]` wrong?](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.foo-bar)

Comment: You seriously need to activate error reporting.

Comment: Also, you are missing quotes around your array keys: `$blog['link-title'];`

Comment: I think you need to put quotes ('') around your array keys. I.e. $blog['url'] & $blog['link-title'].

Comment: Also, *if it's an array and not an empty string* makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing some apostrophes there. Your code should be:

`echo $blog['url'];
echo $blog['link-title'];`